# Angular sending emergency alert to all users

Tags: sql, angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to send an emergency alert to all end-users. Like an "Emergency" Broadcast notification, because if I want to update new versions, they have to save theeir works before half an hour.

I hope its clear now. Once check design of UI you will get some knowledge on this.

Here is design of concept:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqnU.png
[like this i want give emergency alert To All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/julmo.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you have to give live notification to your users whenever you try to update your system. Then you should consider using Push Web Notifications to notify the users or you can also try socket io and implement this type of functionality.

Here are the reference links [Socket IO](https://socket.io/)
,[Push Web Notifications](https://www.airship.com/resources/explainer/web-push-notifications-explained/)

Comment: r you used ? this type of task any where using #Angular,#WebApi,#Sql . actually i don't know about angular i'm new to angular

Answer (score 0):

If it is an real-time & Web Socket implementation you can use `Web socket` or [SocketIO](https://socket.io/) to emit messages. Otherwise you have to use the **Angular PWA** to push notification.

try this to add `PWA` feature to your exist Angular application:

```sh
ng add @angular/pwa
```

Then you have to generate a `VAPID` key pair using node web-push. Install web-push:

```sh
npm install web-push -g
```

generate a VAPID key pair with the following command:

```sh
web-push generate-vapid-keys --json
```

Then you have to subscribe to Push Notifications. here is an sample:

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <button class="button button-primary" (click)="subscribeToNotifications()">
          Subscribe
        </button>
`})
export class AppComponent {

    readonly VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY = "BLBx-hf2WrL2qEa0qKb-aCJbcxEvyn62GDTyyP9KTS5K7ZL0K7TfmOKSPqp8vQF0DaG8hpSBknz_x3qf5F4iEFo";

    constructor(
        private swPush: SwPush,
        private newsletterService: NewsletterService) {}

    subscribeToNotifications() {

        this.swPush.requestSubscription({
            serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
        })
        .then(sub => this.newsletterService.addPushSubscriber(sub).subscribe())
        .catch(err => console.error("Could not subscribe to notifications", err));
    }
}
```

For more information there is complete guide here: [Angular Push Notifications: a Complete Step-by-Step Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/)

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:16:13 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'newsletterService' of class 'AppComponent'.
Found NewsletterService

16     private newsletterService: NewsletterService

Comment: i am getting this @ng-Hobby

Comment: This is a sample to just see how the general process works. It is because you didin't implement class `newsletterService` and inject it in your `app.module.ts` providers. Did you read this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/ ?